# Controlling a KNX gateway with Apple HomeKit

Tags: apple-homekit, knx

Are there any **KNX** gateways that work with Apple **HomeKit**? I'm currently using the BAB Technologie EIBPORT V3 and have to speak to it via CUBEVISION 2 which works very poorly. I would love to find a way to simply control my KNX devices (primarily lighting) using HomeKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't have any personal experience with it, I found [a Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mcv4iMJ-EgI) from ThinKNX which suggests that it would allow you to control KNX lights from Apple Homekit...

They outline [here](http://www.thinknx.com/wiki/doku.php?id=voice_control#integration_with_homekit) how to integrate ThinKNX with Apple Homekit.

Again, I'm afraid I'm not an expert, but I hope this could point you in the right direction!